# Tag synonym proposal - reproject to projection-conversions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[reproject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproject) with 6 questions and no Wiki

[reprojection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reprojection) is already a synonym of [projection-conversions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection-conversions) with 483 questions and a Wiki of "The process of translating a map or spatial data from one geographic projection to another"

Comment: I agree - it won't take too many votes for me to think this one should just happen.

Comment: At the same time I've never been a fan of [tag:projection-conversion] when we already have [tag:projection].

Comment: @PolyGeo Given the frequency of questions on the topic, I think there is room for a distinction between those related to moving between and those more about identifying or selecting the correct one (thing vs act). I was wondering about projection-conversion vs transformation tags (how they have been vs should be used) but that's already raised elsewhere. I guess any time you have a word that is both verb and noun you could potentially run into the issue. Also that many tags are potentially misapplied or could do with some disambiguation - what they were *meant* to do vs what they get put on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already [proposed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/projection-conversions/synonyms) making [reproject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproject) synonym to master [projection-conversions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection-conversions), which seems logical given the Wiki and other existing synonym.

Unfortunately it hasn't garnered much attention and as with any synonym voting, the pool isn't terribly large. I'm at the bottom of the top user list with a score of 8, so there might not be much more than 25 or so people (unless there are a ton of people between 5 and 8) who could vote should they even notice it. IMHO there needs to be a mechanism on the site for calling the attention of eligible voters to proposed synonyms.

Comment: +1 I've voted now

Comment: With some clear agreement and no sign of dissent, I have gone ahead and approved the synonym you proposed.  Thank you for raising it.